# I let management know I'm looking at PhD positions, and now they want to guilt-trip me into quitting

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, termination, pressure

I work as a developer at a relatively large company. I recently started applying for some PhD positions (not related to my company's field), as I feel that might be a better fit for me. My employer could make me happier, but I really cannot complain - the reason for leaving is my interest in research, not dissatisfaction with my current position.

When putting reference contacts together, I thought it would look bad on my application if I didn't have anyone from my current company (I've been here for just over 3 years) to recommend me, so I asked my line manager if he'd agree to be named as a reference contact.

I was hesitant to do so because I didn't want to show my hand too early, but I did it anyway. The two of us had a meeting about it and I made it clear that I intended to give my notice as soon as I got a suitable offer, and that there was nothing management could do to keep me. My manager then said that higher management will probably be willing to keep me only for a month or so. While not impossible, I probably won't get an offer within that time, so that would leave me without income at a critical time.

Legally, they cannot let me go without sufficient reason (which they don't have), so I might be in for some guilt-tripping because they cannot depend on me for upcoming long-term projects. That's an understandable issue, and I can empathize, but I don't feel it's in any way my responsibility.

I'm currently not crucial in any ongoing projects, but I don't expect them to pay me for sitting around - there are plenty of small tasks which could be done on current projects and I can make myself useful.

In anticipation of a follow-up meeting, I should know which stance to take. My line manager told me he wouldn't mention this higher up until after our follow-up meeting - which is shortly before theirs, AFAIK, so maybe there is still time to adjust course.

How should I make it clear that, while I want to stay with the company until I get an offer, I won't give in to the guilt trips, but without getting confrontational? I would also like to avoid having to resort to legal action. Finally, I think there's a big difference between going to another company and going to a non-industrial PhD position - how could I argue that to management, other than *hey, why not support science?*

Comment: what country is this?

Comment: "they cannot let me go without sufficient reason (which they don't have" Where do you live where announcing that you are looking for a new job and telling management that you are unwilling to stay with the company is not sufficient reason for letting you go?

Comment: @sf02 UK (if you have two years service), most of Western Europe (again with some caveats).

Comment: Who is the follow up meeting with, your line manager or the higher-ups? This is critical to getting an answer.

Comment: I know I messed up by telling it too early - it's clear this is damage control.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere they shouldn't directly, that was my point. I believe it's a healthy and sadly lacking perspective in these times, but they don't care in an immediately tangible way.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane the meeting is with my line manager, but shortly before he has (regular) meetings with his higher-up(s). He told me he didn't yet tell it to anyone, and that it's best we sleep on it. But the cat is out of the bag anyway, I suppose.

Comment: "When putting reference contacts together, I thought it would look bad on my application if I didn't have anyone from my current company" - you shouldn't provide references until you're getting an offer and are ready to take it.

Comment: @HorusKol well, the application process explicitly required that I provide references.  That's why I went for it. I wouldn't have done it otherwise.

Comment: I don't know UK law well enough to write an answer, but I'm pretty sure "guilt tripping" you into quitting would be Constructive Dismissal.

Comment: Regrettably, you are another exhibit in why never to give any inkling of plans to leave until the ink is dry on your new position. Hope everything works out. But I would not give into any form of "guilt trip." That's for school kids. Make them walk you to the door if they want to get rid of you.

Comment: For clarification: in your position, would you really be "sitting around" if you're not part of those upcoming long-term projects? Is there nothing that you can do on current projects during the ideal remainder of your tenure?

Comment: @AN of course there would be work for me, there's always stuff to fix, test, refactor, improve. And everybody knows this - in fact, the management likes to brag about taking on more projects than the manpower allows. It seems like a horrid approach which will only cause stress in the long run. So yes - they really need people, and I really don't understand the hurry to get rid of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may be true that  the company must  have a reason in order to fire you (I don't know UK law, so  I'm taking your  statement at face value; where I am in Canada this is assuredly not the case, and regularly happens, it's called "termination not for cause"), that doesn't mean the reason has to be true, verifiable, or even to pass  the "reasonable person" bar.  They can say something like "ReoTheYokel didn't perform  up to standards", and fire you for that, even if they have no  factual  basis for such a statement (at least, this is true in most of the world, unsure of the UK specifically).  So, the statement that they can't  let you go "without sufficient reason", may be factually true in text, but  there are infinite ways they can get around that, to the point it may as well be false.  In particular, in this  case, they may say you  are "not sufficiently  committed" to the company, given that you have already stated  your wish to leave.

As for what to do now: Did you  tell your line manager (whom you asked for a reference) to keep  notice of your leave "on the DL" (so to speak)?   If you didn't, if it's not too late, you may want to do that ASAP.  Let him know you told him in confidence and ask him not to escalate the  issue so you can submit your resignation when you intend to leave.  Assure him that you will continue to work to the best of your ability until then, and then do that.  Don't give him a reason to complain about you.

If you told your line  manager to keep your secret and he didn't, well then you're screwed.  Not only is your secret out in the open, but your manager betrayed you.  In which case, your company seems pretty toxic and you should get out  ASAP anyway.  Your manager respecting you is pretty critical of a good workplace, and if you couldn't even get that, then screw them and get out, whether to a PhD program or otherwise.

If you  did  not ask your line manager to keep your secret and he didn't, that could be an honest error; he may be under  a requirement  to  report this to management, or he may have been asked about it, or something, and may have thought it's not a big deal.  You got burned, but it  might not  have been intentional.  But in any case, you got burned.

It's unlikely management is interested  in listening to  anything you  have to say, but in case they are, simply tell them what you  said here: You want to  continue working at this company, you will continue to work up to your previous standards, but also you  want to enrich yourself (or whatever other verbiage you want to use) by going back  to  school  for a PhD.  If they're already prepared to fire you, this isn't likely to change their mind, but it might, so may as well  try.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't nuanced enough about them "not being able to fire me", to put it lightly. It's pretty vague and workaroundable.
As for the line manager, he agreed to keep it a secret until his regular meeting with a higher-up later this week. So I might be able to adjust course a bit somehow. But I'm afraid some damage is irreparable :/

Comment: @ReoTheYokel Ask your boss if he can keep it a secret permanently, and if  he can't then why not.

Comment: @Ertai87 If (and only if) you have two years service in the UK, it is very hard to get rid of an employee - it has to be for true, honest redundancy (the role does not exist in the business any more) or _gross_ misconduct. Companies attempting to game the system will get the book thrown at them at a employment tribunal and lose lots of money. (Practically, this means employment will end "by mutual agreement" i.e. you pay the troublesome employee enough money to go away quietly, and you promise not to give them a bad reference)

Comment: @PhilipKendall, so presumably it's not hard to get rid of an employee for legitimate reasons of redundancy or gross misconduct (i.e. there being no work to do, or doing the work badly), just hard to get rid of them for illegitimate or fanciful reasons (such as sacking a person who intends to return to academia, despite them having a good conduct record and fully intending to comply with their employer's notice period).

Comment: @Steve Getting off topic for comments so [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59141008#59141008).

Comment: Also dont know about UK laws, but if it is anything similar to other european countries this wont suffice. Bigger companies usually have a board that protects the workers and you need to run anything by them regarding hiring and firing people. 
In other european countries you also cannot be fired "on the spot" unless you did something illegal. So they have to warn you like 2 or 3 times. And it has to be written down. So they have to prove that they gave you time to improve and change undesireable behaviour. 
The bigger the company the harder it gets.

Comment: Sure it can be worked around, no doubt, people still get fired. But you will usually know when you get fired. I mean they need to warn you then wait, warn again, then fire you. And some contracts even have a fire period. Like if they fire you, they have to tell you like 2 weeks in advance or something. And then they need to pay and there is all kind of things depending on country the need to do. 
Again except they find a really good reason like you stole, lost them A LOT of money or worked really recklessly.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I make it clear that, while I want to stay with the company until I get an offer, I won't give in to the guilt trips, but without getting confrontational?

All you need to tell them is that you are not changing your position on the matter and that you will not entertain any offers to do so.

> I would also like to avoid having to resort to legal action.

This will likely be difficult.  You have already told your manager that you are leaving as soon as you receive an offer and that there is nothing the company could do to keep you.  You have essentially resigned.  The company can fire you and attempt to make a legal argument that you resigned, which means you may be forced to resort to legal action.

> Finally, I think there's a big difference between going to another company and going to a non-industrial PhD position - how could I argue that to management, other than hey, why not support science?

Unless management is holding you hostage and the only way to leave this company is to convince them that your course of action is correct, it makes no sense to argue anything about your decision.

In the future, if you decide to leave a company, do not mention anything about leaving until you have already accepted and signed a written offer from your new company.

Comment: Lesson learned, I guess.

Comment: "The company can fire you and attempt to make a legal argument that you resigned": In any juristiction that "needs" a reason to fire someone, this would be a field day for any lawyer. It's absurd. Not saying companies cannot act absurdly stupid, but there are probably better arguments to be found if they want to spent the time looking. You resign when you officially hand in your resignation the way your contract or the local legal default describes.